# Dual SOQL statements syntax

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, error

This trigger will send an email anytime an Account has 5 cases created within 8 days.  I need to create two SOQL queries as I am accessing fields from Case and Project__r.

Currently receiving error message:

> Invalid bind expression type of AggregateResult for Id field of SObject Case

```
List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList = [SELECT AccountId, Account.Name name, COUNT(Id) co
                                         FROM Case
                                         WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:5 
                                         GROUP BY AccountId, Account.Name
                                         HAVING COUNT(Id)  >= 1];

List<Case> caseList =   [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name, Project__r.Implementation_status__c,
                         Project__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c
                         FROM Case WHERE Id IN :AggregateResultList];


            for(Case cl:caseList){ 
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                        if(cl != Null && Project__r.Implementation_status__c == 'LIVE - TRANSITION'){    
                             //Set Outgoing Email to Implementation Coordinator
                             message.toAddresses = new String[] { Project__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c }; 
                        }
                        else if (cl != Null && Project__r.Implementation_status__c == 'Live - Closed Project'){  
                             //Private method *** getAddresses() *** retrieves email address from Customer_Success_Managers Public Group

                             message.toAddresses = new String[] { getAddresses() };
                        } 

                    message.Subject = 'Subject Test Message';
                    message.PlainTextBody = 'Account name: ' + aggr.get('name') + ' has ' + (Integer)aggr.get('co') + ' cases opened in the last 8 days.';
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages =   new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
                    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList ...

... WHERE Id IN :AggregateResultList];
```

This is the problem, as the error is indicating. You're querying against an `Id` field, but binding a collection of `AggregateResult` objects. Those are not compatible types.

You'll need to iterate over the list of `AggregateResult` objects and accumulate their `AccountId` values into a `Set<Id>`. You can then bind the `Set<Id>` into your second query.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I understand what you are saying and it makes sense.  I am just having a bit of trouble with the syntax.

Comment: @ZeroCalm Help me understand how to help. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thank you.  I understand what you are saying and it makes sense.  I am just having a bit of trouble with the syntax.

Set<Id> AcctIds = new Set<Id>();

for(AggregateResult aggr: AggregateResultList){
   AcctIds.add(aggr.AccountId);  
 }

List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, AccoundId, Account.Name, 
                                     Project__r.Implementation_status__c,
                                     Project__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c FROM Case 
                                     WHERE Id IN :AcctIds];
Receiving Error:
Variable does not exist: AccountId

Comment: AggregateResults don't have much in the way of static fields. You need to access their contents dynamically via `get()`: `aggr.get('AccountId')`

Comment: Thanks.  I'm able to print my AccountIds to the console, however when I try to add them to my Set, I get the Error: 'Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(Object) from the type Set<Id>' .

Comment: Set<Id> AcctIds = new Set<Id>();
     for(AggregateResult aggr: AggregateResultList){
                        AcctIds.add(aggr.get('AccountId'));
     }
     List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name, Project__r.Implementation_status__c,
                Project__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c FROM Case WHERE AccountId IN :AcctIds];

Comment: @ZeroCalm The return value from `get()` must be cast to the type `Id`: `(Id)aggr.get('AccountId')`.